# How do I call a class for use in my main function

Tags: python, class, program-entry-point

I want to use a class in my main function but don't exactly how to do it.
Here's what I have tried so far. The following code is only for demonstration purposes.

**Code has been edited to what @furas has suggested.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from class.embed import Embed


def request(r):
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    return r

def data(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.txt, 'lxml')
    title = soup.select('.ac-ln-title-comingsoon')
    return title

def main():
    url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/'
    old_title = None
    while True:
        r = request(url)
        title = data(r)
        if title != old_title:
            url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/'
            embed_class = Embed(url)
            print(price, processor)
        else:
            print('Lorem ipsum')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**This is my class:**

```
class Embed:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.r = request(url)
    def content(r):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.r.text, 'lxml')
        price = soup.select('.column  large-6').get_text()
        processor = soup.select('.techspecs-column').get_text()
```

Comment: first you should use `self` in `__init__(self, url)`. And then you should send `url` as argument `embed_class = Embed(url)`

Comment: you should use `self.` in class - `self.r = request(url)` - to have access to this request in other methods - `BeautifulSoup(self.r.text, ...)`

Comment: don't chage code in question because this way may comments doesn't fit to your code. If you have to change code then add it at the end with text `"EDIT:"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to use `self` as first argument in all methods. When you will run

```
embed_class.content()
```

then Python will runs

```
Embed.content(embed_class)
```

so it will assign instance `embed_class` to `self`

Second you should use `self.` to have access to variables from one method in another method.

Method should also use `return` so you can use its values outside method.

---

BTW:

`select()` gives list (even if it find only one element or it doesn't find any element) so you can't use `select().get_text()` but you have to use `get_text()` on every element separatelly using `for`-loop or list comprehension. ie.

```
 price = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in price]
```

Page has two prices and two descriptions for processor so you may need `for`-loop to display it in more readable way. I display it as list.

I skiped `while`-loop because it was useless for me. I also changed classes in `select()` to get only some part of page.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Embed:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.r = request(url)

    def content(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.r.text, 'lxml')

        price = soup.select('.section-price .column.large-6')
        price = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in price]

        processor = soup.select('.section-processor')
        processor = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in processor]

        return price, processor


def request(url):
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    return r

def data(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.select('.ac-ln-title-comingsoon')
    title = title[0].get_text()
    return title

def main():
    url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/'
    old_title = None

    r = request(url)
    title = data(r)
    print(title)

    if title != old_title:
        url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/'
        embed_class = Embed(url) # it runs only `__init__()`
        price, processor = embed_class.content()
        print(price, processor)
    else:
        print('Lorem ipsum')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

**What i understood from your question is that you want to create an object of that class and pass the url in the parametric constructor and use that in your main function?**

Below should be your main function:

```
def main():
  url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/'
  old_title = None
  while True:
    r = request(url)
    title = data(r)
    if title != old_title:
        url = 'https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/'
        embed_class = Embed(**url**)
        embed_class.content()
        print(embed_class.price, embed_class.productData)
    else:
        print('Lorem ipsum')
```

Below should be your Embed class:

```
class Embed:
def __init__(url):
    r = request(url)
def content(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    price = soup.select('.column  large-6').get_text()
    processor = soup.select('.techspecs-column').get_text()
    productData= soup.select('#name for extracting productdata#').get_text()
```

***Please don't copy the same code i have written. First try  to understand from it. Let me know if any issues. You may have a doubt that how productdata is coming. And that you have to search the query name for productData or else you may know from where you get the productdata from .Rest of the code ,i mean your basic doubt on how to call the class members and use them in main function is clear now.***

Thank you.

Comment: There is no `productData`, that was a typo which is now corrected. Why do have to call `embed_class.content()`, I mean isn't `embed_class = Embed(**url**)` enough?

Comment: @julian `Embed(url)` runs only `__init__`. To get price you have to run also `content()`. But code in this answer is full of bugs.